# Getting uniqe user identifier from Microsoft Account

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app, live-sdk, microsoft-account

I would like to have a Windows Store/Windows Phone 8.1/Universal (UAP) app store data to a database in the cloud. I would like to use the owner ID instead of asking for a sign-up with my backend. No Problem so far. But I would like to allow the user to access the data via a web app as well. If the user signs in via Microsoft Account, will I be able to get the same owner ID?

I understand, that in both cases I can request for the users e-mail address. But as this one can be changed by the user, I don’t want to rely on it.

Maybe you have a similar setup and guide me a bit?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this.  You would need the user to login using the same Microsoft Account via the OAUTH protocol.  The API used for this is here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn631818.aspx